# 'DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint

I received React project from github, and I encountered below error when I typed "npm start".

```
> @devias/material-kit-pro-react@4.1.0 start
> DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start

'DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN' is not recognized as an internal or 
external command, operable program or batch file
```

I guess this is an environment issue.
But I cannot solve it.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can set environment variable:

Windows:

```
set DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
```

Docker:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 8080:3000 -e DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I modified my package.json to work on windows:

set DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true && react-scripts start

set DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true && react-scripts build

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I cannot solve this issue on Windows, but when I run it on MacOS, there is no issue.

If anyone have ideas, let me know.

Comment: This would make more sense as an edit to the question, since it either means there is no problem (on MacOS) or there is no answer yet (on Windows).

Answer (score -1):

node node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js --help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).